# Rails many to many through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have three models Journals,XSLTS and Journals_xslts. I have XSLT files uploaded and have to map the XSLT to the Journals on Journal edit.

But here when mapping XSLT in edit page, i have to include the type of XSLT(now it is two types abstract and fulltext). Maximum chances would be in both types same files will be mapped to the journal.So in edit page I have two select fields seperately,  but the xslt file are commonly populated. On saving the journal I have to map these two XSLT ID to one particular journal in separate table which can be a :through model.

Below are the tables with sample data

[image]

Is there possible to use has_many through association or any-other solution is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not much clear but what I get I think you need one journal can have more than one XSLT if this is the case there are two ways for doing this 1. You can add two column in your journal table (if everytime only two XSLTs need to add) and the second one is generic solution HABTM association https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many